# How can I find out which PID belongs to which script?

Tags: php

i'm building a websocket with php.

I run script with

```
exec('php -q ../ws1/server.php');
```

and

```
exec('php -q ../ws/ws_server.php');
```

with

```
exec('pidof php');
```

i get PID's of running processes/scripts. (eg. 13697 and 13726)

How can I find out which PID belongs to which script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps aux | grep pid
```

This will list all details of process including that script name.

Edit

from script

```
exec("ps aux | grep $pid", $output);
echo $output;
```

Comment: from console? i wanna do it form script.

Comment: thx. Last edit helped (the one with $output added). 
Thx allot.